# Parse json tag inside another tag

Tags: java, android, json

I have a problem with parsing a tag inside another tag.
I have a json file structured like this:

```
 "articles":[
             {
             "source":
                     {
                     "id":"generic-news",
                     "name":"Generic News"
                     },
             "author":" author's name",
             "title":"your title",
             "url":" your url",
             "publishedAt":"date",
             "content":"your content"
             },
```

I don't have problems parsing source, author, title, url, publishedAt and content, but I can't get id and name it just gives me an error. 
This is my code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            //result is the entire json file
            String newsInfo = jsonObject.getString("articles");

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(newsInfo);


            for(int i= 0; i < arr.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.i("source", jsonPart.getString("source"));
                temp = jsonPart.getString("source");
                textView.append(temp+ "\n");
                Log.i("author", jsonPart.getString("author"));
                Log.i("title", jsonPart.getString("title"));
                temp = jsonPart.getString("title");
                textView.append(temp+ "\n");
                Log.i("description", jsonPart.getString("description"));
                temp = jsonPart.getString("description");
                textView.append(temp+ "\n");
                Log.i("url", jsonPart.getString("url"));
                temp = jsonPart.getString("url");
                textView.append(temp+ "\n");
                Log.i("publishedAt", jsonPart.getString("publishedAt"));
                temp = jsonPart.getString("publishedAt");
                textView.append(temp+ "\n");
                Log.i("content", jsonPart.getString("content"));
                temp = jsonPart.getString("content");
                textView.append(temp+ "\n");
        }
```

My app correctly prints author's name, your title, your url, date and your content, but with source it prints {"id" : "generic-news", "name":"Generic News"}.
I tried using the same method that I used with articles but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"source" is not a string, but rather a Json Object. So you'd need to do this:

```
JsonObject obj = jsonPart.getJSONObject("source");
String name = obj.getString("name");
String id = obj.getString("id");
```